# Why does clicking next to a new page just show the entirety of the previous page first?

Tags: webforms

I have three pages on a webform. When I click 'next' page 2 shows the entirety of page 1. The user has to scroll through everything to get to page 2. The same thing if I want them to skip from page 1 - 3 based on one conditional on page 1.

Drupal 7 didn't have all the problems I'm having on Drupal 9 webforms... what happened?

Comment: Sounds like a custom theme issue. To verify, if you change to the default theme "Bartik" does it go away?

Comment: Thanks No Sssweat for the suggestion, but sadly not. I think it has something to do with AJAX and Stripe. If I enable ajax, the problem seems to disappear, but if I do that it means I can't have both a set contribution and a voluntary donation on my payment page...